# Possible Turing degrees of countable models of ZFC

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, computability

Let $M$ be a countable model in a signature $\Sigma$. We assume $\Sigma$ is finite, and (for convenience) has no function or constant symbols.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $M$'s object set is a subset of the natural numbers. We can then ask about the Turing degree of $M$'s object set, as a set of natural numbers. Furthermore, for each $n$-ary relation $R$ in $\Sigma$, we can ask about the Turing degree of $M$'s interpretation of $R$ (considered as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ , where $n$-tuples of natural numbers (objects of $M$) have been coded as single natural numbers). We then define the "Turing degree of $M$" to be the least upper bound of the degree of its object set and the degrees of all of its relations.

Question: If ZFC has a model, does it have a countable model whose Turing degree is bounded by $\emptyset^{(n)}$ for some finite $n$?

Comment: Yes. Any consistent theory with an r.e. axiomatization does. Just go carefully through Henkin's proof of the completeness theorem. The argument gives you a $\Delta^0_2$ model.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: That sounds like an answer to me! Care to write it in the answer box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and that we are considering $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is not really relevant (except that for $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we know we do not have a recursive model):

If $T$ is a consistent theory with an r.e. axiomatization, we can carry out the argument of Henkin's proof of the completeness theorem for $T$, and obtain a $\Delta^0_2$ model of $T$ whose universe is a recursive set of numbers.

(I do not know who this result is due to, maybe Hartley Rogers, Jr., who mentions it as exercise 14.11 in page 332 of his book **Theory of recursive functions and effective computability**.)